# Enforce git commit -m header size

Tags: git

I want git to reject a commit if the first `-m` option is a string of more than 50 characters.

#### Desired behaviour:

```
$ git commit -m "AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMMNOOPPQQRRSSTTUUVVWWXXYYZZ"
Error: Could not commit, header size larger than 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use git hooks to achieve this kind of functionality.

I believe you might be looking for a post commit hook.

You could then write a bash script to check the message entered in the commit message and then ask the user to change it.

Maybe then trigger a `git commit --amend` instantly so that they are forced to change it

http://githooks.com/

Comment: I ended up using prepare-commit-message. I did not know about git hooks, thank you! Learn something new everyday.